# Failing Azure File Copy when deploying a release to test environment with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release, file-copying, azureportal

So I'm trying to add a new task, Azure File Copy, to my release pipeline.  The file copy is pulling a single file from a new Azure Repository I created in Azure DevOps recently and putting it into a specific blob container. However, I seem to be running into an error

`[error]AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired. Visit the Azure Portal to create new keys for your app, or consider using certificate credentials for added security: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials`

I tried looking for possible solutions for this, but considering this is a new repository, I'm not sure what I need to do. With my current existing app, I do have access to Microsoft Azure portal. With the link that's given in the error, it talks about updating the certificate, but it never had one to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failing Azure File Copy when deploying a release to test environment with Azure DevOps

You could try to check if the service connection fails in Azure DevOps if you are using the Service Principal account to create the connection.

The service principal credential lifetime defaults to one year.

[image]

If yes, please create new credentials, and then update the Service Connection in Azure DevOps.

You could check [this blog](https://blog.rassie.dk/2019/08/update-azure-active-directory-service-principal-credentials/) and [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-4.5.0) for some more details.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET environment variable on the machine running the task, is set to a key that has expired.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10